# How to get milliseconds from DateTime column using SqlDataReader?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, sqldatareader

I have a datetime column `DateCreated` in sql with value `2015-03-31 15:44:08.197`

In vb when I run the command `sqlreader("DateCreated")` I am only getting the value:

`3/31/2015 3:44:08 PM`

How to I retain millisecond precision in vb?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I am only getting the value"? Are you just printing out the default string representation, or have you checked that the `DateTime` you receive *really* doesn't have anything for milliseconds?

Comment: What I am receiving does not have anything for milliseconds.

Comment: How are you validating that, how are you seeing the value *with* milliseconds, and what does the schema for the column look like? (What's the exact column type?)

Comment: Column type `DateCreated (datetime, not null)`. I'm inspecting the value as it is getting assigned. I'm only seeing the value with milliseconds in the db, not when I retrieve it.

Comment: *How* are you inspecting it, precisely?

Comment: Setting a break point and inspecting it through quick watch.

Comment: Inspecting it through quick watch how though, exactly? Looking at the `Milliseconds` property, or just a string representation? (If you could just show a console app which prints it out using a custom format string which shows the milliseconds, that would help...)

Comment: Can you show us value from database. Just copy from database and print here.